# Choosing to color five or six petals of an eleven petal flower

Tags: combinatorics

This is a question from one of the competition books.

> Amira has drawn a flower with $11$ petals. She wanted to paint some of the petals yellow. Are there more ways to paint $6$ petals or $5$ petals yellow?

I thought there are more ways to choosing $5$ petals yellow compared to number of ways to chose $6$ petals yellow. But the answer seems to be

> Both ways of choosing results in same number of ways!

Can anyone help clarify?

Answer (score 3):

So she either has to choose six petals to color yellow or choose five petals to color yellow. But since there eleven petals, you can think of this as a decision between

- choosing six petals to color yellow, or
- choosing six petals **not** to color yellow.

This results in the same number of options for Amira.

---

There are some formal combinatorics behind this problem. Let $n \choose k$ denote the number of ways to [choose $k$ things out of a collection of $n$ things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). This number can be calculated explicitly as
$$
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k!)}\;.
$$
So in the case of this problem, we can notice that
$$
{11 \choose 5} =
\frac{11!}{5!(11-5)!} = 
\frac{11!}{(11-6)!6!} = 
 {11 \choose 6}\;.
$$